# Django M2M relationships: Use just one intermediary table or one per entity pair?

Tags: django, database, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

When creating many to many relationships we use an intermediary table. Lets say I use the following entities `video`, `category`, `tag`, and `VideoCategory`, `VideoTag` to create the relations.

I'm assuming that many tags/categories can have many videos and vice-versa.

And I do it with `through` keyword 'cause I want to be able to use extra fields in the future if I want.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag

class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, through='VideoCategory')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, through='VideoTag')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class VideoCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    video = models.ForeignKey(Video, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class VideoTag(models.Model):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    video = models.ForeignKey(Video, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

But I was wondering if would be possible to create a `taxonomy` entity and handle the relationships with categories and tags from just one place.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag

class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, through='Taxonomy')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, through='Taxonomy')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Taxonomy(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    video = models.ForeignKey(Video, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now the `taxonomy` entity would hold the `category` and `tag` related to videos and vice-versa.

I've included 'null=True' to be able to create relations with categories without tags and with tags but without categories.

If I don't use it. I receive an error:

```
# sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: MyApp_taxonomy.category_id
```

This also means that using that single `taxonomy` entity for the two relationships could have many `NULL` Fields if one of these `category` or `tag` fields are empty on every concrete relation instance (row).

## Question:

What would be better ? To keep the intermediary tables separate (VideoCategory & VideoTag) Or to join these intermediary tables into just one ? (Taxonomy)

---

Due to my lack of experience with databases I couldn't say if I'm missing something important. If doing it with just one intermediary table would give problems in near future or something like that... Of if it is just fine.

Comment: I guess that my second example is producing ambiguous related fields. This way django cannot know which field should it use right ? This is why I should use through_fields attribute, to specify them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `through_fields` argument ([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#manytomany-arguments)):

```
class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, through='Taxonomy', through_fields=('video', 'category'))
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, through='Taxonomy', through_fields=('video', 'tag'))
```

Comment: If I understand it correctly. These two lines would sit inside the `Video` entity. Then in the attribute `through_fields=('video', 'category')` these two fields would refer to the `video` and `category` fields in the `Taxonomy` entity with the `models.ForeignKey(x)` being `x` the entity `Video` or `Category` That's right ?

Comment: May anyone edit and add an example to show how an insert should be done using these relations ?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#manytomany-arguments

Comment: I've made a follow up question based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49573288/how-to-insert-using-m2m-relationship-and-intermediary-table-and-through-fields