# How to implement a form to add a video using M2M model with through_fields?

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-related-manager

I have this model from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49463876/django-m2m-relationships-use-just-one-intermediary-table-or-one-per-entity-pair):

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag

class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, through='Taxonomy', through_fields=('video', 'category'))
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, through='Taxonomy', through_fields=('video', 'tag'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Taxonomy(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    video = models.ForeignKey(Video, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How should I implement a form that let me create a new video, with their associated categories and tags using these models bearing it mind it has and intermediary table using `through_fields` ?

**NOTE**: Use edit history (revisions) to see the previous questions before I reworded It.

Comment: The definition of a through model is that you create a row for every relationship between the two models you're linking - i.e., you have to create a `Taxonomy` instance for every cat/tag that is linked to a video. If you don't want to do that, then a through model isn't the right approach. I am not sure whether you need your `Taxonomy` model at all - why can't you just have m2m relationships between video/tag and video/category?

Comment: I wanted to have a custom intermediary table. For future needs.

Comment: In which case you have to create one `Taxonomy` object for each relationship that you want to save.

Comment: In the shell it forces me to create an instance for each relationship, I see it now. But using forms too ? Couldn't I pass a list of arguments and django handle that ? Maybe I should reword my question On how to implement this using an add form.

Comment: I have reworded the whole question.